# Customview is null with findViewById

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to reference a custom view from my layout, but the customview is always null. I do it as follow:

MainActivity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.mainview);
TView tnew= (TView) findViewById(R.id.tview);
```

`tnew` is `null`.

mainview.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainview_with_flipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/simpleViewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/layout_timeline"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <firm.package.gallery.GalleryRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/gallery_view_size"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">
            </firm.package.gallery.GalleryRecyclerView>

            <firm.package.timeline.TView
                android:id="@+id/tview"
                android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ViewFlipper>
</LinearLayout>
```

When debuggin, I can see that following constructor from TView is called:

```
public TView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
```

Can someone give me a hint how to reference correctly ?

Comment: Are you passing the `AttributeSet` in the super constructor call? If not, that's your problem, as the ID will never be assigned.

Comment: That was it. Thanks a lot. Would you like to give an answer and I will accept ?

Comment: Cool. It's actually a pretty common issue, however, so I'll mark this as a duplicate, rather than repeat an answer. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!